# Changing text depending date using MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I'm switching the text depending on dates and using JavaScript.

```
<div id="test"></div>

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = new Date() > new Date('2021-12-05') ? 'A' : 'B';
```

but I want to use Razor to finish this. Can anyone give me any advice?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this:

```
@if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2021, 12, 5))
{
    <div id="test">A</div>
}
else
{
    <div id="test">B</div>
}
```